# Is there any way to convert from `org.testng.ITestResult` `ITestNGMethod` to `java.lang.reflect.Method`

Tags: java, testng

I want to get the test method that was executed each time when the test class is run. I use the following code

```
@AfterMethod
public void logout(ITestResult result){
  Method method=result.getMethod(); //compliation error- Type mismatch: cannot convert from ITestNGMethod to Method
 readAnnotation(method);
}
```

Is there any way to convert from `org.testng.ITestResult` `ITestNGMethod` to `java.lang.reflect.Method`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't you want `getConstructorOrMethod()` as per [the documentation](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/ITestNGMethod.html#getConstructorOrMethod--) ? Then `getMethod()` on the returned `ConstructorOrMethod` object will give you the underlying method